# List comprehension from itertools.cycle generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, cycle

My problem was that I needed to deliver batches from an `itertools.cycle` generator in list form.

A [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) takes an iterable and loops it around itself indefinitely. For example:

```
>>> my_cycle = itertools.cycle('abc')
>>> next(my_cycle)
'a'
>>> next(my_cycle)
'b'
>>> next(my_cycle)
'c'
>>> next(my_cycle)
'a'
```

And so on.

The question becomes, how do we deliver a list of batch length `n` from a cyclic generator, while preserving where we are in the cycle?

Desired output is:

```
c = itertools.cycle('abc')
batch_size = 2
Out[0]: ['a', 'b']
Out[1]: ['c', 'a']
Out[2]: ['b', 'c']
```

I am posting my solution in case someone runs into the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037927/extract-a-list-from-itertools-cycle

Comment: @AK47 rephrased, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) designed for this:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle


def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))


c = cycle("abcdefg")
take(5, c)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems like [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) was made for this:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> size_of_batch = 5
>>> c = cycle('abcdefg')
>>> list(islice(c, size_of_batch))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> list(islice(c, size_of_batch))
['f', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> size_of_batch = 5
>>> c = itertools.cycle('abcdefg')
>>> [next(c) for _ in range(size_of_batch)]

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> [next(c) for _ in range(size_of_batch)]

['f', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```